# Why different versions of same compiler is giving different outcomes?

Tags: c++, floating-point, stdout, codeblocks

I was trying to calculate **n<sup>th</sup>** harmonic number. Here's the main snippet of my program:

```
#include<cstdio>

int main(){
    int T; scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int C = 1; C <= T; C++){
        int n; scanf("%d", &n);
        long double H = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            H += (1.0/i);

        printf("%.8lf\n", H);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program on my machine (inside *Code::Blocks* IDE, compiler *gcc 5.1*), everything seems fine.

**Input:**

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Output:**

```
1.000000
1.500000
1.833333
2.083333
2.283333
2.450000
2.592857
2.717857
2.828968
2.928968
```

But when I run it inside an [online editor, it prints zero](https://ideone.com/FPzDJz) instead. Here, the compiler is *gcc 8.3*.

I want to know the reason behind this phenomenon and the way to avoid this so that I can get my expected output.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't get into the habit of using `*scanf()` ("scan *formatted* data") for scanning potentially malformed (user) input. Reading a line of input and then parsing that with more powerful functions (e.g. `strtod()`) gives more robust behavior. If you *have to* use `*scanf()`, *always* check its return value to make sure you actually *did* read data into your variables. -- That's for C. With C++, you *really* should use `<iostream>` instead of `<cstdio>`...

Comment: advice acknowledged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should turn on your compiler warnings. It helps a lot with things like these. If you would have done so it would show:

```
warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'long double' [-Wformat=]
   15 |         printf("Case %d: %lf\n", C, H);
      |                          ~~^        ~
      |                            |        |
      |                            double   long double
      |                          %Lf
```

So this should give you a similar result in both versions:

```
int n; scanf("%d", &n);
long double H = 1;

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    H += (1.0/i);

printf("%.8Lf\n", H);
```

Comment: You know, *Code::Blocks* is so user friendly that it sometimes doesn't show compilation error if I forget to include a header file from what I'm using a function on my code. Anyway, how to enable compiler warnings? I thought I already had them enabled by default.

Comment: not sure how Code::Blocks does it, but the compiler flags `-Wall -Wextra` should be enough for most cases. You can silence warning types that you don't need/don't apply to your cases

Comment: With Code::Blocks, it may vary with version.   However, typically, the settings to turn on warnings are found by the menu "Project->Build Options ...".  That brings up a dialogue with a number of tab, one of which is "Compiler Settings".  Scroll down and check the warnings desired  (if there are + signs showing, a set of options is hidden and the one labelled "Warnings" may be expanded).  Check the options to "Enable all common compiler warnings (overrides many other settings) [-Wall]" and "Enable warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++ [-pedantic]" at a minimum.

Comment: Note that "at minimum" really means "bare minimum". You really should check the conpiler manual and run *the strictest error checking mode possible*. Grepping from the Makefile of one of my projects, something like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Winline -Wno-long-long -Wuninitialized` is by no means overkill.